# React Native: OnPress being triggered before OnBlur

Tags: react-native

I have the following code:

```
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)

async function checkIfEmailAlreadyRegistered() {
    const email = context.getValues('email')


    if (email) {
      try {
        setLoading(true)

        const response = await isAlreadyEmailRegistered(email)

        if (!response.data.valid) {
          context.setValue('email', profile.email)

          return Alert.alert('', response.data.message)
        }
      } finally {
        setLoading(false)
      }
    }
  }

// bellow, there is a snippet of my form, specifically the input that is causing 
// the trouble.

<Form
                required
                name='email'
                onBlur={checkIfEmailAlreadyRegistered}
                as={
                  <Input
                    label='Email'
                  />
                }
              />

// as you can see, when the input is triggered and then is out of focus, the function 
// checkIfEmailAlreadyRegistered is called

// finally, there is the submit button

<Button onPress={submitForm} disabled={loading}> Submit </Button>
```

The thing is: the button should not be pressable until the email is validated.
The code works when the user interacts with the input and then click anywhere else, but
it does not work when the user interacts with the input and then clicks on the button.
This is happening because the "onPress" function in the button is triggered before the "onBlur" function
at the email input.

I would appreciate any tips or insights on how to solve this problem.

Comment: You are currently disabling the button on load. You can set disabled={checkIfEmailIsValid()} you can use a useEffect to track the changes and set a disabled prop

Comment: could you give me an example? @Craques